# What is the order of $\tau = (5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9)(3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(2\ 3\ 4\ )(1\ 2)$? Is $\tau$ an even or an odd permutation?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

In $S_9$, what is the order of $\tau = (5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9)(3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(2\ 3\ 4)(1\ 2)$? Is $\tau$ an even or an odd permutation?

For the first question: I tried to write $\tau$ as the composition of disjoint permutations but failed miserably. However, I made an explicit definition for the permutation $\tau$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau(1) &=& 4\\
\tau(2) &=& 1\\
\tau(3) &=& 6\\
\tau(4) &=& 2\\
\tau(5) &=& 7\\
\tau(6) &=& 3\\
\tau(7) &=& 8\\
\tau(8) &=& 9\\
\tau(9) &=& 5\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now I noticed that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau^3(1) &=& 1\\
\tau^3(2) &=& 2\\
\tau^2(3) &=& 3\\
\tau^3(4) &=& 4\\
\tau^4(5) &=& 5\\
\tau^2(6) &=& 6\\
\tau^4(7) &=& 7\\
\tau^4(8) &=& 8\\
\tau^4(9) &=& 9\\
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\tau^n(k)$ means you apply the permutation $\tau$ to $k$, and then apply it to the result etc. for $n$ times. The powers appearing are $2,3,4$ so the order of $\tau$ is the smaller common multiple and since $\gcd(3,4)=1$ this is equal to 12. Therefore the order of $\tau$ is 12. So I found what I think is the correct answer but I do not really like the method and was wondering if anyone knows a better more elegant way to solve this.

For the second part I re-wrote $\tau$ as:
$$\tau = (5\ 6)(6\ 7)(7\ 8)(8\ 9)(3\ 4)(4\ 5)(5\ 6)(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(1\ 2)$$
which is the composion of ten 2-cycles which means $\tau$ has order $(-1)^10=-1$. I am pretty confident about this last part but I just wanted to add it for completion. If anyone knows a nicer way to determine the order of $\tau$ I would be happy to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: Are u working in $S_9$?

Comment: Yeah sorry I am working in $S_9$.

Comment: @Babak: does it matter?

Comment: Your original idea of writing $\tau$ as a product of disjoint cycles is a good one, you just need to practice doing this. Once you have it written like this, you can determine the order as the lcm of the cycle lengths, and you can determine whether it is even or odd by counting the number of cycles of even length.

Comment: @vadim123: Certainly it doesn't make any different, I just wanted to ask and know. :-)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is there any sort of efficient or nice algorithm to write a cycle as the composition of disjoint cycles?

Comment: Here is how I usually go about writing down a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles: Write $1$, then write down what $1$ is sent to next to it. Then write down whatever that is sent to next to it. Repeat until you get a $1$, and close that cycle. Now pick the next element not appearing in the cycle you wrote and repeat the process until there are no elements left.

Comment: Ah thanks, that's actually what I was doing, however in my original attempt I made the mistake of accidentally writing $\tau(1)=5$ which messed up the cycles. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: $Babak I am not familiar with GAP to be honest. is it a code to check these kinds of questions?

Comment: @TeunVerstraaten: I'll post them below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You found the explicit two-line representation

$$\tau=\binom{123456789}{416273895}\;;$$

from that it’s straightforward to decompose $\tau$ into disjoint cycles. Start with $1$: it goes to $4$, which goes to $2$, which goes to $1$, so you have a cycle $(142)$. That takes care of $1$ and $2$, so move on to $3$: it goes to $6$, which goes right back to $3$, giving you the cycle $(36)$. Continuing in this fashion, you get one more cycle, $(5789)$. Thus,

$$\tau=(142)(36)(5789)\;.$$

And now it’s apparent that the order of $\tau$ is the least common multiple of $2,3$, and $4$, which is (as you discovered the hard way!) $12$.

Your determination that $\tau$ is even is correct, but you can do it even more easily from the disjoint cycle decomposition: odd cycles are even permutations, and *vice versa*, so here we have a composition of one even and two odd permutations, which is even. Or you can write out

$$\tau=(14)(12)(36)(57)(58)(59)\;.$$

(Those are composed from left to right.)

Answer (score 2):

These are the codes in which you can *just* test your work computationally:

```
 > G:=SymmetricGroup(9);
 > g:=(1,4,2)(3,6)(5,7,8,9);
 > Order(g); 
                                              12
```

Comment: Ah awesome, where do I enter this though? Sorry for noob question!! I am used to programming in Matlab and C++ and stuff and little bit of Maple

Comment: @TeunVerstraaten: I think you'd better try GAP as well. It is masters in symbolic computation like Maple also. :-) By the way, You can consult about it via GAP forum. :-)

Comment: Cool, I will check it out

Comment: $\quad \Large + 1 \;\land \;\ddot\smile\;$

Comment: +.*`,+. `,+.*`,+.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ °,+.* `,+.*`.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ `,+.*`,+.* `,+.*`,+.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ °+.*`,+. `,+.*`,+.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ °,+.* `,+.*`.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ `,+.*`,+.* `,+.*`,+.*`,+.*’`,+.* ..`’ °´..`’ °+*•.¸¸.•*´+`*•.¸¸.•*´+`*•.¸+¸.•*´`*•.

Answer (score 1):

You did a nice job on both parts.  What I would do differently for the first part is instead of writing out the permutation explicitly I would write it in cycle structure; that makes it easier to see the order, and it's a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to evaluate the product of the permutations.

The trick for determining whether the permutation is odd or even is to split each permutations into cycles.  You have done well with writing out the cycle structures.  Count the total number of cycles, so we have 10 cycles.  Thus, we have even permutation.

OR

You can also count the order of each permutation.  That is: Determine the number of cycles for each permutation.  For instance, if you have $(5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9)$, then there are $5 - 1 = 4$ cycles.  The quick formula for this is to first count the total numbers in the permutation.  Then, subtract that by 1 to get the order of the permutation.

Work out other permutations the same way and add up all the orders, so we have:

$$(5\ 6\ 7\ 8\ 9)(3\ 4\ 5\ 6)(2\ 3\ 4)(1\ 2)$$
$$(5 - 1) + (4 - 1) + (3 - 1) + (2 - 1) = 10$$

Thus, the permutation is even.